# SQLite database iPhone data

Tags: iphone

I opened a SQLite database file, and it seems to have many rows that aren't readable.
The data has got weird symbols including "question mark diamonds". Is it data that iPhone encrypts when it goes to the database and decrypts back? Is there a way to read the data?

What are my chances of decrypting it? Where do I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[`encoding != encryption`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4657456/1953464)**

What you describe as *non-readable* and *weird symbol characters* does not necessarily suggest encryption. What it means is, there are some parts of data using characters that can not be visually represented by the software you're using to read them.

This could be either visual representation of non-printable control characters (such as [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return), [linefeed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline),...) and are substited with a visual representation characters of software designers' choice, or extended range [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) characters that the application you're using to read this data back can't represent by the font and character set it's using, be it by design, or by improper character reperesentation settings in it (if supported at all).

In short, [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) used isn't supported by your data inspector, and for all we know, it might as well be binary data stored in a [BLOB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object) field. This, however, doesn't automatically suggest the fields are encrypted in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Apple encrypts data using a CommonCrypto library and I would guess what you are seeing is SQLCipher.   Details to be found in the manual.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000157

Also I recommend reading these:
http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-iphone-sqlite-encryption-with-sqlcipher/
http://sokol8.blogspot.no/2011/05/iphone-sqlite-data-encryption-sqlcipher.html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929744/encrypting-sqlite-database-file-in-iphone-os

Comment: Is there any tool to decrypt the database? I dont care to decrypt each value. I run windows 7 btw

Comment: I believe this has been asked before, eg. take a look at the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665945/decryption-using-sqlcipher-in-iphone

Comment: Andy - this answer would be much more valuable if you could summarise the bits in that link that answer the question. This also helps protect against link rot.